# When ever i get notification my application opens in background just show the notification and not open the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications

It's able to show the notification but opens the app in background.

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExpertActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sendmessageicon);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sendmessageicon)
                .setContentTitle("Dummy")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(-1)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: @sanyasiraomopada i want to start the intent of expert activity when clicked on notification but the app starts in the background every time i get a new notification

Comment: Can u pls try this  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ExpertActivity.class), 0);

Comment: Thanks this worked. @GaneshGudghe

Comment: if it work for u please accept my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ExpertActivity.class), 0);
```

Comment: i am still working on my reputation once i get it i will accept it sorry as of now i need 15 to accept.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: No not working still opens the application in background when i receive a text